# Bootstrap php button click event to load another page using value from the first

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

The codes first:

**transactions.php**

```
<tbody>

    <?php
    include 'database_connection.php';
    $sql = "SELECT `id`, `date`, `name`, `phone`, `subtotal`, `status` FROM `sales`";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td>
            <td> <?php echo $row['id'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['phone']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['subtotal']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['status']; ?> 
            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" id="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" onclick='view(this.id)'>View / Print</button>
        </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>

<script>
function view(id){


    $.ajax({
        url: "invoice_view",
        type:"post",
        data:{ val : id },


        success: function(result){

            window.open ("invoice_view.php","mywindow");

    }
    });
}
</script>
```

**invoice_view.php**

```
<?php
    include 'database_connection.php';
    $data=$_POST['val'];
    $user_id=$data;
    $sql = "SELECT `name`, `phone`, `town`, `date`, `item1`, `item2`, `item3`, `item4`, `item5`, `item6`, `item7`, `item8`, `q1`, `q2`, `q3`, `q4`, `q5`, `q6`, `q7`, `q8`, `taxper`, `amt1`, `amt2`, `amt3`, `amt4`, `amt5`, `amt6`, `amt7`, `amt8`, `taxtotal`, `subtotal`, `status` FROM `sales` WHERE id=$user_id";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):
        ?>
```

So I am trying to pass the id of that specific transaction to the invoice_view.php page so it loads that specific transaction.

The screenshot of the transactions.php page is:  http://oi65.tinypic.com/2ngh24l.jpg

Please help me figure out where am I doing wrong? The invoice_view isn't even receiving the value I'm sending from the transactions page.

Comment: It will receive the data from the ajax request. But the `window.open` will run a new instance of the php script and will have no post data

Comment: how do i fix that?

Comment: Must it be a post? A GET would let you just use an `<a>` link and pass id in the url and not require any javascript. Note you are open to sql injection by not parameterizing your queries with either post or get

Comment: I am not sure how to do that ?

Comment: Do what? Both issues easy to research

Comment: Using GET to pass the value.

Comment: Then read up on how to use `$_GET` and how url search params work

Comment: I tried searching but not getting any proper results, maybe I am searching using wrong terminologies.

Comment: `<a href="invoice_view.php?someQueryParam=someValue">` and use `$_GET['someQueryParam']` instead of `$_POST['someQueryParam']`

Comment: Let me give it a try. Thanks

Comment: Still unable to pass the value to the next page

Comment: So what happens? Can see what is passed in query string right in the address bar and a simple dump of $_GET would show you what it sees

Comment: <td><a href="invoice_view.php?someQueryParam="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"" class="btn btn-default">Print</a></td>

Comment: $data=$_GET['someQueryParam'];
 $user_id=$data;

Comment: I tried like that but the url shows: http://localhost/cms/invoice_view.php?someQueryParam=

Comment: If I manually add http://localhost/cms/invoice_view.php?someQueryParam=10 or any id it does work but it's not sending it to the page on click

Comment: You have mismatched quotes in the html

Comment: No, I double checked

Comment: Can clearly see them in comment above. Should be no quotes wrapping the id echo and those extra quotes cause the html href to end before the echo

Comment: Oh that, thank you so much, it worked like a charm now.